# How can I format a date?

Tags: c#, .net, date, format

```
        //This will get the month as an int (e.g. 4)
        DateTime dLastMonth = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
        int iLastMonth = dLastMonth.Year;
```

How can I make the above code output 01, 02, etc... instead of 1, 2, 3...

Comment: Have you tried google? The very first hit for `c# datetime format` was http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: If you want to format the whole date, why are you extracting just the year part?

Comment: I think he thought if the month is January, removing a month, what year will it be... Wild guess.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused by your question, but if you want to format it into a string (01, 02, 03 etc) use:

```
var formatted = iLastMonth.ToString("D2")
Console.WriteLine(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

But all you need to do is :

```
Convert.ToInt32(dLastMonth.Year.ToString("yy"));
```